# Copying a collection of objects to another collection without duplicates using aggregate operations

Tags: java, collections

I have a `List` of items named `items` and am copying this list to a `Set` using:

```
 List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    items.add(new Item("Suremen Body Spray", 1900, 45));
    items.add(new Item("HP wireless mouse", 5500, 5));
    items.add(new Item("UWS USB memory stick", 1900, 8));
    items.add(new Item("MTN modem", 1900, 45));
    items.add(new Item("MTN modem", 1900, 45));

    Collection<Item> noDups = new LinkedHashSet<Item>(items); //Copy items to noDups

    //Print the new collection
    noDups.stream()
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

When I run the code, all the items are copied into the collection as shown in the output.

[image]

A different test using just Strings works just fine:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

    names.add("Eugene Ciurana");
    names.add("Solid Snake");
    names.add("Optimus Prime");
    names.add("Cristiano Ronaldo");
    names.add("Cristiano Ronaldo");


    Collection<String> itemCollection = new HashSet<String>(names);
     itemCollection.stream()
           .forEach(System.out::println);
```

[image]

What method can I use to copy the list into the set without the duplicate? Are there any aggregate operations for this, or do I have to write a custom method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement the [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) and the [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) method in your `Item` class.

Comment: Don't be so sure that a hash code isn't mandatory. The contract requires a custom hash code with a custom `equals`, and `HashSet` may miss duplicates if the contract is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I add an answer to show how I finally did it (Using Adam's suggestion of course)

I added the implementations of the `equals` and `hashCode` methods to my Item class:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(!(obj instanceof Item)) {
        return false;
    }
    if(obj == this) {
        return true;
    }

    Item other = (Item)obj;
    if(this.getName().equals(other.getName())
           && this.getPrice() == other.getPrice() 
           && this.getCountryOfProduction().equals(other.countryOfProduction)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;

    hash = 7 * hash + this.getName().hashCode();
    hash = 7 * hash + this.getCountryOfProduction().hashCode();
    hash = 7 * hash + Double.valueOf(this.getPrice()).hashCode();
    return hash;

}
```

Comment: You can simplify/shorten the above code using `Objects.hash()` and `Objects.equals()` (since Java 7) or Guava's [Objects](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html) or Apache Commons Lang's [HashCodeBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) and [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html)